# How to split data by whitespace

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have data in a text:

W S 6
W H 11
W D 6
W C 8
W N 9

N S 7
N H 2
N D 6
N C 5

N N 4
E S 6
E H 11
E D 6
E C 8
E N 9

and I want to split them to a string array like:

```
string[0] array=
"W S 6
W H 11
W D 6
W C 8
W N 9";

string[0] array=
"N S 7
N H 2
N D 6
N C 5";

string[0] array=
"N N 4
E S 6
E H 11
E D 6
E C 8
E N 9";
```

I had been do:

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(uploadedFile.InputStream))
                {

                    string read = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    string[] Array = Regex.Split(read,"\n");
                }
```

But It cannot done, Pleas help me.

Comment: Try `var arr = read.Split(new[] {"\r\n\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` (or `"\n\n"` if the endings are `LF`), see [this demo](https://ideone.com/XKs4Nd).

Comment: See my answer with two approaches explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split with double line break:

```
var read = "W S 6\r\nW H 11\r\nW D 6\r\nW C 8\r\nW N 9\r\n\r\nN S 7\r\nN H 2\r\nN D 6\r\nN C 5\r\n\r\nN N 4\r\nE S 6\r\nE H 11\r\nE D 6\r\nE C 8\r\nE N 9";
var arr = read.Split(new[] {"\r\n\r\n", "\n\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.Write(string.Join("\n-- NEXT ITEM ----\n", arr));
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/XKs4Nd)

Output:

```
W S 6
W H 11
W D 6
W C 8
W N 9
-- NEXT ITEM ----
N S 7
N H 2
N D 6
N C 5
-- NEXT ITEM ----
N N 4
E S 6
E H 11
E D 6
E C 8
E N 9
```

Note that if your line breaks are not consistent, you will have to add all possible variations to the first `Split` argument.

Or use a `Regex.Split`:

```
var arr = Regex.Split(read, @"(?:\r\n?|\n){3,}").Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m));
```

See [another C# demo](https://ideone.com/mZkrzU).

Here, `(?:\r\n?|\n){3,}` matches 3 or more  (`{3,}` is a limiting quantifier)
 line breaks: CR followed with an optional LF (`\r\n?`) or (`|`) an LF (`\n`).

See a [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%7C%5Cr%29%7B3%2C%7D&i=W%20S%206%0D%0AW%20H%2011%0D%0AW%20D%206%0D%0AW%20C%208%0D%0AW%20N%209%0D%0A%0D%0AN%20S%207%0D%0AN%20H%202%0D%0AN%20D%206%0D%0AN%20C%205%0D%0A%0D%0AN%20N%204%0D%0AE%20S%206%0D%0AE%20H%2011%0D%0AE%20D%206%0D%0AE%20C%208%0D%0AE%20N%209).

Answer (score 1):

You tried to split by newline (`\n`). You need to split by space:

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(uploadedFile.InputStream))
{
     string read = reader.ReadToEnd();
     string[] Array = Regex.Split(read," ");
}
```

Or even better by whitespace (space, tab, ...)

```
string[] Array = Regex.Split(read,"\s");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to split the text on newlines ..

```
string[] array = read.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```